# Web page: Use font X for English characters, font Y for Russian characters...etc can this be done?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have a web page full of mixed characters and I want to allocate a font for a language instead of having "one font fits all", are there any solutions to this?

My pages are UTF-8 encoded, I prefer HTML/CSS solutions first, JS if necessary.

Thanks.

Comment: P.S. You'd probably get more people looking at your question if you gave it more related tags.  You could certainly have tagged this "HTML" and "CSS" along with "fonts".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<p lang="en">English text.</p>
<p lang="ru">Russian text.</p>
```

CSS:

```
:lang(en) { font-family:A; }
:lang(ru) { font-family:B; }
```

[CSS :lang selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-lang)

Comment: @stockoverflow: Apparently, yes. Note that it doesn't work in Internet Explorer 6 and 7.

Answer (score 1):

This may be way too late for your needs, but I just happened to see this question. The simplest way I can think of is to surround each section of Russian with a  tag that has a class attached to it.  Then define one set of CSS for your regular body text, and another set of CSS for the text inside the span.

HTML:

```
<p>English English English. 
<span class="russianText">Russian Russian.</span> 
English English again.</p>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
span.russianText {
  font-family: Times New Roman, serif;
}
```

Comment: Well I guess after 2 months if this is the best method then I'm up for it.

Comment: My original idea was to have Javascript figure out the language (i.e. a certain range of UTF-8 would be English, Russian etc...)